# How to return partial view from Nancy Module as a result of ajax call

Tags: ajax, partial-views, nancy

I have following method in one of my nancy modules

```
Get["/settings/dropdown"] = x =>
            {
                //create model here
                return View["DropDownPartial", model];
            };
```

I am calling this method from an ajax request and I want my view to return `HTML` without using the `Layout` page. I have defined layout page for my application using `ViewStart.cshtml` which looks like

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

and this `Layout` setting is also applied to `DropDownPartial`. How can I effectively override the `Layout` settings in this scenario and tell `nancy` to return only `HTML` contained in this view?
I have tried to set

```
@{
Layout = null;
}
```

and

```
@{
Layout = "";
}
```

in the view but neither of them worked. Any ideas, how I can get around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another layout, you can call it `_EmptyLayout.cshtml`, with just the following code:

```
@RenderBody()
```

and use that layout to your partial view.